# PHP Formatting A Column (dollar sign) In csv Upload Script

Tags: php, csv

I have a script that uploads a csv file with 3 columns (phone, name, amount). The script removes any formatting on the phone, ie; ()- and puts the file on the server. The amount column in the file shows the amount like 125.00 and I need it to show $125.00. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$file_destination = '/****/****/****/***/' . $file_name_new;

$contents = file_get_contents($file_tmp);

$contents = str_replace("(","",$contents);
$contents = str_replace(")","",$contents);
$contents = str_replace("-","",$contents);

file_put_contents($file_tmp, $contents);

if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
```

Comment: Instead of doing blanket str_replace and possibly removing valid characters, why not just use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) and turn it into an array. Then you can loop over and edit each/any column or value.Then fputcsv to write the array back.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. You want to change the value stored in the CSV file from `125.00` to `$125.00` or you want to output the values formatted as such?

Comment: I need the amount  to show the dollar sign in front of it. If it's possible to simply format that 3rd column as currency, that would be great.

Comment: If by "show" you really mean "display in your spreadsheet software" then this really has nothing to do with either PHP or CSV. CSV files are simple, flat, comma-separated-value files. They have no embedded formatting options. Your spread sheet software may have such display options, but then that isn't a question for StackOverflow. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you want to reformat the values strictly for output or store the new formatted data in your CSV file, it's probably going to be more effective to use `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv`. Those functions are designed for properly reading in and writing out CSV formatted files.

### Example

```
$rows = [];
if (($handle = fopen($file_tmp, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        list($phone, $name, $amount) = $data;
        $phone = str_replace(['(',')','-'], '', $phone);
        $amount = sprintf('$%.2f', $amount);
        // you can build a new array with the updated values
        $rows[] = [$phone, $name, $amount];
        // or output directly
        echo "$phone | $name | $amount";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

// if you want to save the destination with the updated information...
$fp = fopen($file_destination, 'w');

foreach ($rows as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```